# How can i retrieve all custom registered taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

i am trying to find a way to retrieve all registered taxonomies

i was looking at get_taxonomies() but i cant seem to get only the custom registered ones.

any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in taxonomies are registered with the parameter `_builtin` set to `TRUE`. To get all custom taxonomies, ask for `'_builtin' => FALSE`:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function()
{    
    $taxonomies = get_taxonomies( array( '_builtin' => FALSE ) );
    print '<pre>' . print_r( $taxonomies, 1 ) . '</pre>';
});
```